# Restrict IAM role permission S3:PutObject to buckets that contain certain tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to setup a IAM role such that any container/lambda/ec2 that assumes that role would only be able to upload an object to S3 buckets that contain a tag key (or key+value).

I tried policy like:

```
{
    "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringEqualsIgnoreCase": {
            "aws:ResourceTag/key_to_have": "true"
        }
    },
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "*",
    "Sid": "AllowPutObjectToS3BucketsWithTags"
}
```

I tried with condition variable `aws:TagKeys` and `s3:ExistingObjectTag` (this obviously wouldn't work but tried) but still received permission denied during `s3.upload_file()` call. Is it possible to setup a policy to be able to upload/put object to S3 buckets with tags?
This works without any condition (have to restrict by S3 bucket name only).

Comment: No, that is not possible.